# How to clip a movie from specified start and end time in ffmpeg end of the 50 seconds ago?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want clip a movie specified a start and end time use ffmpeg I have get set start time work will but I want set a end time Finally, the end of the 50 seconds ago. I don't know how to set configure.

```
ffmpeg -i demo.mp4 -ss 00:01:20 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k -mbd 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 new_demo.mp4
```

Comment: like a movie full 00:00:00 to 01:04:00; i want clip 00:01:20 to 01:03:10; because Each movie full time are different so need set in Countdown 50 seconds end

Answer (score 0):

The sane method is to parse the ffmpeg readout of the input info for duration and then supply a `-t` value of `duration - start time - 50s`.

The insane method is to feed the input twice and use the overlay filter:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2:10 -i demo.mp4 -ss 00:01:20 -i demo.mp4 -filter_complex overlay=shortest=1[v] -map [v] -map 1:a -shortest -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k -mbd 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 new_demo.mp4
```

The first input has a ss value of start time + amount of end part of video to be cut.

The second input has a ss value of your start time.

Basic idea is that the overlay filter can be made to terminate when the shortest input ends. The first input is set a ss value so that the overlay ends when the interval from end is reached.